# How do I get wmic to use a delayed variable in a for loop?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, escaping, wmic

I'm stuck and need your help please:

I am trying to test for the existence of a specific application and version within a batch file so I can uninstall non current versions.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set currver=7.1.10.21187
set appname=Juniper Installer Service
set junver=1
echo %currver%
echo %appname%
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('wmic product where "name='%appname%'" get version /VALUE ^| find "Version="') do (echo version: %%i
set junver=%%i
echo Juniper version detected: !junver!
if !junver! NEQ %currver% (echo non-current version found...
echo ...uninstalling %appname%
wmic product where ^( name='%appname%' and version='!junver!' ^) call uninstall
echo !errorlevel!
echo %appname% uninstalled))
echo.
echo %junver%
```

All of the code works except for the second wmic command that contains the code: and version='!junver!'
I have tried adding the double carat to escape the exclaimation marks to no avail, also using the %%i variable also does not work.

I have also tried using the different where filter syntaxes also to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited to process the subroutine in a loop:**

If you use this style of coding then you don't need extra care in escaping.
I can't test the code though... the `call uninstall` looks odd to me there.

Spaces and `&` characters can be an issue if you have them and make sure that the `junvar` variable from the WMIC command doesn't have a trailing CR.

```
@echo off
set currver=7.1.10.21187
set appname=Juniper Installer Service
set junver=1
echo %currver%
echo %appname%
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('wmic product where "name='%appname%'" get version /VALUE ^| find "Version="') do set "junver=%%i" & call :next
echo done
pause
goto :EOF

:next
echo Juniper version detected: "%junver%"
if %junver% EQU %currver% goto :EOF
echo non-current version found...
echo ...uninstalling %appname%
wmic product where (name='%appname%' and version='%junver%') call uninstall.bat
echo %errorlevel%
echo %appname% uninstalled
echo.
echo %junver%
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Cheers for this, it does uninstall the version that is found last.  however, on my computer, I have 2 versions installed and I want to uninstall the non-current versions.  so I need to cycle through each one that it finds and test if it is the current version, then uninstall if it is not the current version.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is your problem : http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266

You can try also with this change in your code:

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%B in ('wmic product where "name='%appname%'" get version /VALUE ^| find "Version="') do @for /f "delims=" %%i in ("%%B") do (
echo version: %%i
set junver=%%i
echo Juniper version detected: --!junver!-- 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your original script (so you can check if each instance installed on the computer is the current version and remove non-current versions):

edit this line:

```
wmic product where ^( name='%appname%' and version='!junver!' ^) call uninstall
```

to this:

```
set juniperuninstall=wmic product where ^( name='%appname%' and version='!junver!' ^) call uninstall
```

then add this line straight after:

```
cmd /c !juniperuninstall!
```

this changes the wmic line into a readable format which gets read into a fresh command instance.
not clean, but works.